# php pdo driver library none found

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm trying to deploy  'limesurvey' application into the PCF & I get the following error.

```
php pdo driver library none found
```

Below are the pre-requisites that should be met for installation.

```
• mbstring (Multibyte String Functions) extension library
•PDO database driver for MySQL (pdo_mysql or pdo_mysqli) or Postgres (pdo_pgsql) or MSSQL (pdo_sqlsrv for Windows and pdo_dblib for Linux)
•Also we assume in general that all PHP default libraries are enabled (like hash, session, etc.).
```

Is there any workaround for this ? Because, few sites says to modify the `php.ini` file, which I don't have access to. If the suggestion is to have my own buildpack, is there any link that I can refer to do that please.

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the limesurvey application is using php-buildpack, you can tell the buildpack to load the mbstring and pdo_* modules by creating an options.json file in the .bp-config subfolder, if it doesn't already exist, adding a PHP_EXTENSIONS key, and including the name or names of the modules/extensions that are required in the value.

Something like this:

```
$ cat .bp-options/options.json
{
    "PHP_VERSION": "{PHP_56_LATEST}",
    "PHP_MODULES": ["cli"],
    "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["mysqli", "pdo_mysql", "mbstring"],
    "ADDITIONAL_PREPROCESS_CMDS": [""]
}
```

Even though the php-buildpack calls mbstring and pdo_mysql 'modules' you want to list them in the PHP_EXTENSIONS key, not the PHP_MODULES key.